# Django WebTest - "Click" the first of two identical links

Tags: django, webtest

I'm using [Django-WebTest](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-webtest) to test a page which contains two links, both with the same `class` and `href`, and no `id`. I'm reading through the [WebTest docs](http://webtest.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html#webtest.response.TestResponse.click) and can't seem to find a nice way to click the *first* matching element.

I'd really like to avoid hackish things like checking an element's DOM parents or siblings because it will cause tests to break if the designers change the page layout.

This seems like it's a problem that should have a simple solution, especially with a well developed framework like WebTest. Am I just overlooking something obvious?

I can add an ID to one of the elements, but it would seem like a hack since it would be changing the code just to make a test work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Really simple:

```
resp.click('link', index=0)
```